# How to Update Configuration product attribute set in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, attribute-set

I am trying to update my configuration product by programmatically and i want to assign attribute set to configurable product.

I have also checked `catalog_product_super_attribute` table
after updated product but nothing changed

> $attr_ids = array(12,13);
>
> $savedConfigproduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attr_ids,
> $savedConfigproduct);

Any guide will be appreciated.